# Batch file redirect to an empty file when using php exec() to call that batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I have a Windows batch file `gcloud_batch.bat`:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token > token.txt
```

And php file:

```php
exec("gcloud_batch.bat", $output, $return);
```

When I run the php file from browser, it creates `token.txt` but empty. But it work nicely when I run the batch file from command line.

What am I missing?